# Multi source maria db to aws db replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have same problem and need same idea how to solve the problem please help.
I have multiple mysql/maria db and I want to replicate to one db on aws.Multi source db to one db or multi master to one slave.Is this posible?I read that aws rds not support multi master replication only one master to slave and I test this and is working but I have multiple master db?Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with RDS. You can only do it if you run your own MariaDB installation on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Is posible ec2 instance that is replication of all another mariadb to make master to rds?

Comment: No, Aurora is no different in this regard.